# How to propagate negation down to literals?

Tags: pyeda

I would like to transform an expression so that all negation operators are propagated down to the literals. So `~(a | b)` becomes `~a & ~b`. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```py
from pyeda.boolalg.expr import expr

formula = "~(a | b)"
e = expr(formula, simplify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a pair of methods to switch back and forth between the conjunction and disjunctive normal forms.

`.to_dnf()`

`.to_cnf()`

try,

```
>>> e.to_dnf()
And(~a, ~b)
```

Comment: ok, but that's computationally expensive and not the same as propagating negation down  to the literals